# How to Install and configure Open Web analytics module on Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, openwebanalytics

I have a drupal site and i installed the owa module on it.
I cant find a good manual how to install and configure it properly.

Readme.txt from from the owa module on drupal says
Installation

1)* Copy the 'owa' module directory in to your Drupal
sites/all/modules directory as usual.

Usage

2)In the settings page enter your Open Web Analytics SiteID and the Open Web Analytics installation url.

after installing owa module on drupal the 1) step is ok
I dont know where to find the SiteID and which url to write on the settings page.
Do i have to download and copy also all the owa folder to the owa folder on drupal?
What i have to do exactly??

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, go to Reporting on your OWA dashboard, on the lists of the sites you are tracking, look for the site for which you need its ID and URL, click Get Tracking Code in the row of that site. The popup window thats comes up has all the information you are looking for. Hope this helps :)